# How to display a recurrence meeting for all recurrence days

Tags: sql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSGdJ.png)I want to display a recurrence meeting in a list using a SQL.
Table: Events
Attributes: EventId, EventName, EventStart datetime, Event End datetime, EventType

Expected Output

```
Event: Daily scrum
Date: 3rd Dec 2022, 10am

Event: Daily scrum
Date: 4th Dec 2022, 10am

Event: Daily scrum
Date: 5th Dec 2022, 10am

Event: Daily scrum
Date: 6th Dec 2022, 10am

Event: Daily scrum
Date: 7th Dec 2022, 10am
```

can someone help me to achieve this in SQL?

Comment: Please show both sample input data and expected output.

Comment: I pass start and end date as input, like meetings from Dec 1st to Dec 15th. Added sample image in description